# NativeScript ListView won't display my data

Tags: angular, listview, nativescript

I'm really new to NativeScript, decided to do a basic app with it... So I create a service using HttpClient... Anyway, when i do console.dir(events) the data displays in the console, when i use a label, it displays too but it just wont show in my ListView 
 Here is my template:

```
    <StackLayout class="page">
    <ListView [items]="events" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item.theme"
                   class="list-group-item"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

My conponent has this:

```
    constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getEvents();
      }


        getEvents(){
            this.eventService.loadEvents().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.events = {...data};
                    console.dir(this.events)
                },
                error => this.error = error
            );
        }
```

and my service is this:

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

    loadEvents(){
        return this.http.get<Event>(this.baseUrl)
            .pipe(
                retry(3),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );

    }

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.error(
                `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
                `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
        return new ErrorObservable(
            'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
    };
```

I'll really appreciate the help... Thanks in advance

Comment: You view has a binding to an `eventList` property, but I don't see it exposed on your component..

Comment: Thanks...that happened wen i was trying to figure out the problem... I still not displaying